# Passing Function name as arguments to a function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, function-calls

Is it possible to pass the name of a function(say A) as an argument to another function (say B), and then call function A from function B. That is the function name will be stored in a variable in B, and using it call the function whose name is in the variable. For Example in C++ sort function the first and second arguments are iterators, but the third argument is the name of a function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502068/is-there-a-formal-name-for-a-function-that-accepts-a-functions-as-an-argument/47634215#47634215

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can introduce a template parameter (here `Pred`) for "anything that is callable with two parameters":

```
template <typename Iter, typename Pred>
void mysort(Iter begin, Iter end, Pred predicate)
{
    --end;
    // ...
        if (predicate(*begin, *end))
        {
            // ...
        }
    // ...
}
```

Then you can pass either good old C function pointers or C++ function objects:

```
bool function(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y;
}

struct function_object
{
    bool operator()(int x, int y)
    {
        return x < y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {543, 6542654, 432514, 54, 45, 243};
    mysort(numbers + 0, numbers + 6, &function);
    mysort(numbers + 0, numbers + 6, function_object());
}
```

As you can see, a function object is an object of a class that overloads `operator()` appropriately.

Comment: `mysort(numbers + 0, numbers + 6, function);` should also work, since "[a function is implicitly convertible to a pointer to itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7111275/1174378)".

Comment: Can we use the template method for functions requiring 4-5 parameters?

Comment: @AlphaMineron Sure, the parameter `Pred predicate` does not state any requirements on the type `Pred`. Only through the usage `if (predicate(*begin, *end))` will the compiler check that it is callable with 2 arguments. If you need 5 arguments, then simply call it with 5.

Answer (score 5):

You should read up on [Function Pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

simple example with Function Pointers:

```
#include <iostream>

int apply(int (*fun)(int,int), int a, int b) {
    return (*fun)(a,b);
}

int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
int multiply(int a, int b) {return a * b;}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int added = apply(add, 2, 4);
    int multiplied = apply(multiply, 2, 4);

    std::cout << "added result: " << added << std::endl;
    std::cout << "multiplied result: " << multiplied << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
added result: 6
multiplied result: 8
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, not only is it possible, but has great usage as well.

Technically, these are known as [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Conceptually, they are required to have *callback* mechanisms. Callbacks might be required for [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) programs. E.g., your application might be interested to know when a mouse-button is clicked. In this case you would register your interest to the underlying platform for a mouse click event, and tell it what method/function should be called in your program, so that you can execute code accordingly.

Another such case is where programs have an asynchronous mode of execution. E.g., in case a file is to be written to hard disk, which is a time consuming process as compared to doing arithmetical calculations. So, it might be a case where we do not want to wait performing calculations while we are writing results to a file. A program might choose to just call a *write* function on a file and return and start calculations. While, calling this function the caller might also specify a *callback* function. So, when the file is written successfully or fails, the callback function is called and the *callee* informed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Technically, it's not quite the 'name' that's passed, but rather, actually a pointer to the function being passed.