# pass function by value (?) instead of function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I was unable to find it.

So im trying to educate myself about templates and the new C++11 features (mainly lambdas, something I always liked in other languages).

But in my tests I came to something I had no idea it worked, and I'm trying to understand how it works but cant figure it out..

The following code:

```
template <class Func>
void Test( Func callback ) {
    callback( 3 );
}

void Callback( int i ) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    Test( &Callback ); // this I was expecting to work, compiler will see its a pointer to a function
    Test( Callback ); // this also works, but how?!
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand how templates work, basically they're a scheme for the compiler to know what to build, so the first call `Test( &Callback );` I was expecting to work because the compiler will see the template receives a function address and will assume the arguments should be a pointer.

But what is the second call? What is the template assuming it is? A copy of a functio (if that even makes any sense)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A function is implicitly convertible to a pointer to itself; this conversion happens pretty much everywhere.  `Test(Callback)` is exactly the same as `Test(&Callback)`.  There is no difference.    In both cases, `Func` is deduced to be `void(*)(int)`.

Function pointers are weird.  You can find out more about them in ["Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goin)

Comment: thanks for the answer. so if i didnt use templates and declared Test like: void Test( void (*callback)(int) ){...} both calls would work as well. thats good to know. ill make sure i read the thread you linked.

Comment: Why does `Test<void(int)>( &Callback );` work? Is a function pointer also implicitly convertible to its "value type"?

Answer (score 3):

Functions are implicitly convertible to function pointers.  If fact there is no way to get a function value or reference.  Though oddly you can create a function value type, you just can't assign anything to it.

[Here is code snippit](http://ideone.com/u5pAH) that demonstrates how lambdas and various callbacks react with templates.

Comment: This is wrong. Function references are fine. If `Test` were declared as `void Test( Func &callback )`, then `Func` would be deduced to `void(int)`, and `Callback` would be passed by reference, without being converted to a pointer, to `Test`.

Comment: Wow! I guess it make sense that reference should be supported as well as pointers since they are so similar.  Is it possible to declare a function value, and assign something to it?

Comment: @deft I don't know what that means. What's a "function value"?

Answer (score 2):

In C++, functions are not first-class objects, which means “function as value” makes no sense in it. That's why function name has always been implicitly convertible to pointer to it.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting than there are languages where “function by value” does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 11 (and boost and tr1) we have std::function as a template type for storing functors, lambdas and functions. So you can definitely have the concept of keeping a function value in a variable of type std::function. that variable can also be "empty" meaning that no function (reference) is stored in it. Then it cannot be called.

The original question relates to that in contrast to C, C++ allows function references. Plus, for compatibility reasons with C a function name can degenerate to a function pointer. But because of overloading things are more "interesting" in C++ than in C.