# Can a function type be a class template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers

The code below is rejected by VC++ 2012 with "error C2207: 'A::bar' : a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type".

```
int Hello(int n)
{
    return n;
}

template<class FunctionPtr>
struct A
{
    A(FunctionPtr foo)
        : bar(foo)
    {}

    FunctionPtr bar;
};

int main()
{
    A<decltype(Hello)> a(Hello);

    return 0;
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gcc is a bit more friendly regarding this error :

```
error: field 'A<int(int)>::bar' invalidly declared function type
```

The simplest solution is to declare `bar` as a function pointer :

```
FunctionPtr *bar;
```

In this case, `decltype(Hello)` evaluates to `int(int)` not `int(*)(int)`.

Comment: So what is the compatible solution? If instead of passing &Hello, he passed a struct that has overloaded the operator(), this would work fine. How does one write generic code that can accept either a function object or a function pointer?

Comment: @NHDaly `std::function` should work fine, as it takes template parameters in taht format

Comment: @NHDaly A [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)-based approach works (you can take a look at my answer for the details).

Answer (score 6):

Variables cannot have function types. You declare `bar` to be `FunctionPtr` which is `decltype(Hello)` which evaluates to `int (int)`, not a function pointer type.

It's confusing because of some inconsistencies inherited from C. When you define the constructor for `A` as taking a `FunctionPtr` you might imagine you'd get the same error. However, function parameters declared as having an array or function type automatically (unfortunately, inconveniently) get turned into pointer types. So even though `foo` is declared to have a function type it actually has function pointer type and works fine.

But this rule applies only to function parameters and not other variables, so `bar` actually does have a function type, which is not legal.

Comment: thanks for actually explaining why this confusing situation arrises

Answer (score 4):

Adding on the other answers, you can take advantage of the fact that:

- `decltype(Hello)` evaluates to `int (int)` (not to a function pointer type);
- a function is implicitly convertible to a pointer to itself; this conversion happens pretty much everywhere (e.g. [pass function by value (?) instead of function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7111251/3235496)).

The following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class F>
struct A
{
    A(F foo) : bar(foo) {}

    typename std::conditional<std::is_function<F>::value,
                              typename std::add_pointer<F>::type,
                              F>::type bar;
};
```

is a generic solution allowing the same syntax for functions, function pointers, functors and lambdas:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

void Hello() { std::cout << "Function\n"; }

struct Hello2 { void operator()() { std::cout << "Struct\n"; } };

void Hello3() { std::cout << "Function pointer\n"; }

template<class F>
struct A
{
  A(F foo) : bar(foo) { bar(); }

  std::conditional_t<std::is_function<F>::value, std::add_pointer_t<F>, F> bar;
};

int main()
{
  A<decltype(Hello)> a(Hello);

  Hello2 h2;
  A<decltype(h2)> b(h2);

  A<decltype(&Hello3)> c(&Hello3);

  auto Hello4 = []() { std::cout << "Lambda\n"; };
  A<decltype(Hello4)> d(Hello4);
}
```

(here I've slightly changed the solution taking advantage of C++14 features).

Indeed `std::function` is a (not always better) alternative.

Comment: In your solution, you use 'T' which is not a template parameter. I think you meant 'F'.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this today - if you run it with `decltype((Hello))` should be fine without having to change the code. See Scott Meyers for details