# Passing function (without pointer) as argument to another function

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I'd like to know what is the difference between these two (seemingly correct) ways of passing a function to another function:

```
void fun(int p(int x));

void fun(int (*p)(int x));
```

Also, I know that in the second case we're passing a function pointer, but is the first approach also a function pointer (but without the star)?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111251/pass-function-by-value-instead-of-function-pointer) answer your question?

Comment: It is the same behavior of passing an array, in the first case you pass a function object that is referred by a pointer to a function (be careful a function pointer could be different from a standard pointer) using an implicit compiler conversion, in the second case you explicitly pass a function pointer.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. @CoryKramer That was actually helpful information. I also liked the array analogy :).