# Is there a formal name for a function that accepts a function(s) as an argument?

Tags: language-agnostic, higher-order-functions

Is there a formal name for a type of function that accepts a function(s) as an argument?

I've tried searching for the answer to this question but I haven't been able to find it either here or via Google.  Perhaps there is no formal name?

Comment: higher order function?

Comment: @aka.nice Yes, that appears to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Higher-Order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) I think.